# kubernetes Deployment. how to change container environment variables for rolling updates?

Tags: deployment, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Below is how I am using kunbernetes on google.

I have one node application let's say **Book-portal**.

node app is using **environment variables for configurations**.

**Step1:** I created docker file and pushed

```
gcr.io/<project-id>/book-portal:v1
```

**Step2:** deployed with following commands

```
kubectl run book-portal --image=gcr.io/<project-id>/book-portal:v1 --port=5555 --env ENV_VAR_KEY1=value1 --env ENV_VAR_KEY2=value2 --env ENV_VAR_KEY3=value3
```

**Step3:**

```
kubectl expose deployment book-portal --type="LoadBalancer"
```

**Step4:** Get public ip with

```
kubectl get services book-portal
```

now assume I added new features and new configurations in next release.

**So to roll out new version v2**

**Step1:** I created docker file and pushed

```
gcr.io/<project-id>/book-portal:v2
```

**Step2:** Edit deployment

```
kubectl edit deployment book-portal

---------------yaml---------------
...
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          run: book-portal
      strategy:
        rollingUpdate:
          maxSurge: 1
          maxUnavailable: 1
        type: RollingUpdate
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            run: book-portal
        spec:
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: ENV_VAR_KEY1
              value: value1
            - name: ENV_VAR_KEY2
              value: value2
            - name: ENV_VAR_KEY3
              value: value3
            image: gcr.io/<project-id>/book-portal:v1
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: book-portal
...
----------------------------------
```

I am successfully able to change

```
image:gcr.io/<project-id>/book-portal:v1
```

to

```
image:gcr.io/<project-id>/book-portal:v2
```

But I can not add/change environment variables

```
          - env:
            - name: ENV_VAR_KEY1
              value: value1
            - name: ENV_VAR_KEY2
              value: value2
            - name: ENV_VAR_KEY3
              value: value3
            - name: ENV_VAR_KEY4
              value: value4
```

1. Can anyone guide with what is best practices to pass configurations
   in node app on kubernetes?
2. how should I handle environment variable
   changes during rolling updates?

Comment: If the answer is correct, could you accept it?

Answer (score 8):

I think your best bet is to use configmaps in k8s and then change you pod template to get env variable values from the configmap see [Consuming ConfigMap in pods](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/)

edit: I appologize I put the wrong link here. I have updated but for the TL;DR
you can do the following.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
 name: special-config
namespace: default
data:
 special.how: very
 special.type: charm
```

and then pod usage can look like this.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test-container
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox
    command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
    env:
      - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: special-config
            key: special.how
      - name: SPECIAL_TYPE_KEY
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: special-config
            key: special.type
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Thanks for response. can you provide example in context of my question ?

Comment: I apologize i put the wrong documentation link in here I have updated and also copied there example to here for posterity